# Introducing new data against the model, but an error is produced test data does not match model !"

Tags: r, machine-learning

In the R code below, I have included sentences when looking to compare the manually classified with lexicon dictionary results by positive, negative and neutral (in matrixdata1). The algorithms results for the model produces different outcome in the tables, which is good. However, when executing the below

```
"results2 = classify_models(container2, models)"
```

..when feeding in new data **(matrixdata2)** against the model it produces an error message:

```
"Error in predict.svm(model, container@classification_matrix, prob = TRUE,  : 
  test data does not match model !"
```

Please can you help on this problem?

**Update(17/04/20):**

I now understand the train set's sentences used to create the model contains specific words, but the new data fed against the model include new words not recognised in the train set. I am wondering how to overcome this problem. Few options I am thinking of are  the following:-

- Limit sentences in the new data to include only words that are in the train set,
- Or point the ML to consult the dictionaries to look up additional words
- Or for the machine learning process to identify ones that match and ones that do not match simply say I don't know response from ML.

What do you think is the best option to overcome the problem? How would this reshape the R code below?

```
#Load Libraries
library(RTextTools) #RTextTools available for 3.4.1
library(e1071)
library(gmodels)

setwd(directory/path)
text= read.csv("matrixdata1.csv", header = FALSE)

# build dtm
matrix= create_matrix(text[,1:2])
mat = as.matrix(matrix)

# build the data to specify response variable, training set, testing set.
container = create_container(mat, as.numeric(as.factor(text[,3])),
                             trainSize=1:672, testSize=673:840,virgin=FALSE)

models = train_models(container, algorithms=c("MAXENT" , "SVM", "RF", "BAGGING", "TREE"), set_heldout = 168) 

#container1
results1 = classify_models(container, models)

text2 = read.csv("matrixdata2.csv", header = FALSE) 
matrix2= create_matrix(text2[,1:2])
mat2 = as.matrix(matrix2)

container2 = create_container(mat2, labels=NULL, trainSize=1:500,testSize=NULL, virgin=TRUE)

#Results from feeding in new data against the model
#When running this code below, it produces the error message outlined above in the description of the problem.
results2 = classify_models(container2, models)
```

[Datasets used in the R code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GhzOY4IupXXFxKUPaiBsNgpZwxY84Xha?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you able to train your model?

Comment: @neelg Yes I can train the model, but when feed in new data and execute "results2 = classify_models(container2, models)"  it produces the error message as outlined above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when creating the second matrix, I need to refer back the first matrix DTM, this can be done within the second create_matrix() using this argument "originalMatrix". In addition, I need to refer to only the text in column 1 when creating both matrices. These modifications will allow new data to be compared against the model.

Answer (score 1):

Check the format of the train and test data. The error means that the test data is not like the training data, i.e. the configuration of shapes in the model is not compatible with the test data.

If the data you have is is not similar then you can try to fix it. But if the test data is similar to the train data then I recommend splitting the training data itself to derive the test data. This would help you to troubleshoot the issue further to find out what is wrong.

Comment: I understand train set's sentences used to create the model contains specific words, but the new data fed against the model include new words not recognised in the trainset. I am wondering how to overcome this problem. Few options I am thinking of: limit sentences in new data to include only words present in the trainset, or for ML consulting dictionaries to lookup additional words, or ML to identify that match and for ones that do not match say I don't know response from ML. What is the best option to overcome the problem? What would I need to translate this idea in adapting the R code?